# SSH Server status in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, openssh

I wanted to know if there is a way to find out the status of the `ssh server` in the system using Python. I just want to know if the server is active or not (just yes/no). It would help even if it is just a linux command so that I can use python's `popen` from `subprocess` module and run that command.

Thanks

PS: I'm using `openssh-server` on `linux (ubuntu 12.04)`

Comment: Do you mean the local server? What did you already try?

Comment: @wRAR, yes, the same machine that i'm running the python script on.. 
I have have tried to ping port 22 (using python's Popen) and similar things.. Wanted to know something simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a generic way of telling if a process is running you could use `ps`.

```
def IsThisProcessRunning( ps_name ):
  ps = subprocess.Popen("ps axf | grep %s  | grep -v grep" % ps_name, 
                        shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  output = ps.stdout.read()
  ps.stdout.close()
  ps.wait()

  if re.search(ps_name, output) is None:
      return False
  else:
      return True

IsThisProcessRunning('/usr/sbin/apache2') # True, if Apache2 is running.
```

If you have a name that is commonly used; you can specify the location e.g. `/usr/sbin/apache2`

To be safe you can in combination to looking for the process name, also look for the pid file. This is a common technique used in [init.d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) scripts.

```
try:
    pf = file('/var/run/my_program.pid', 'r')
    pid = int(pf.read().strip())
    pf.close()
except IOError:
    pid = None

if pid:
   # Process is running.
```

Comment: Why would I need to wrap the first letter with `[]`?

Comment: Otherwise it will return the ps command, e.g. `grep --colour=auto ssh`.

Comment: @sandeepraju I updated the source with a way to remove the grep without the need for brackets.

Comment: There is also [psgrep](https://code.google.com/p/psgrep/). Alternatively, you can search the `/proc` filesystem yourself.

Comment: Yep, and if the program has an pid file you could check and see if it exists as well, but I prefer to use pid + ps.

Comment: -1 for a common but imprecise solution.  What if I am searching for a process called `pingrepeater`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck xf will give you the full path to the process. So if you have a commonly used name you can specify the full location e.g. `/usr/bin/pingrepeater`.

Comment: I also added an example how to check for the `pid` file that can be used in sensitive cases.

Answer (score 0):

Run `service sshd status` (e.g. via `Popen()`) and read what it tells you.

Comment: When I try that command on my console, it says, `sshd: unrecognized service`. Then I tried `service ssh status` and it works.. says, `ssh start/running, process 787`.

Comment: Yeah, I think it depends on which distro you use what the service name is.  Anyway, I hope that helps and you can parse its output (or just dig in and see how that command works so you can do what it does).